# Do Ramadan fasts count towards kaffrah fasts

Tags: ramadan, kaffarah

So i broke my fast, which I am very ashamed about, I wanted to ask that does the fasts of Ramadan count toward the kaffarah fasts or do we have to keep them separately from that of Ramadan

Comment: Kaffarah fast can basically only done in the remaining 11 months.

Answer (score 1):

The fasting in Ramadan and the fasting for Kaffarah are two separate obligations. Doing one does not exonerate you from the other.